# Twisted structure sheaves for $X=\operatorname{Spec} k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, line-bundles

Consider the twisted structure sheaves $\mathcal O_X(n), n\in \Bbb Z$ for X a closed subscheme of $\mathbb P^0_k$ for $k=\overline{k}$ a field.

By definition, $\mathcal O_X(1):= i^*{\mathcal O_{\Bbb P^0_k}(1)}$,
where the only possible closed immersion $i:X\hookrightarrow \Bbb P^0_k$ I can think of in this situation is the identity.

Then $\mathcal O_X(1)= \mathcal O_{\Bbb P^0_k}(1) = \{0\}$ since all polynomials on $\Bbb P^0_k=\operatorname{Spec} k$ have degree $0$ except the $0$-polynomial which have all degrees (in particular degree $1$).

Then for $n\ne 0$ we have $\mathcal O_X(n)=\mathcal O_X^{\otimes n} = \{0\}$ and $\mathcal O_X(0)=k$ since the graded ring $k$ has only degree $0$ (i.e. constant) polynomials.

### Edit

What confuses me is that $\mathcal O_X(n) \cong \mathcal O_X$ on distinguished open sets as we can read in [Gathmann notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf) Example $7.1.2$ page 122.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{P}^0_k =\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is affine, quasicoherent sheaves correspond to modules, and closed immersions correspond to ideals.

The ideals of $k$ are 0 or $k$, so the closed immersions to $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ are the identity and empty scheme.

On those schemes, the only invertible sheaf is the structure sheaf. Therefore, $O_X(n)=O_X$. You wrote $O_X(n)=O_X^{\oplus n}$ but it should be $O_X(n)=O_X^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the $\otimes$. I still don't see the mistake in my reasonning as I just follow the definition of the twist. Any reason why $\mathcal O_X$ is the only invertible sheaf?

Comment: @Conjecture on an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R$, the invertible sheaves are exactly the sheaves $\widetilde{M}$, for $M$ a projective rank 1 $R$-modules. When $R=k$ is a field, the only such module $M$ is $k$, the regular module, which has $\widetilde{k}\cong\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} k}$.

Comment: @Conjecture Another thing to note is that $\mathbb{P}^0_k = Proj(k[x])$, so not all polynomials on $\mathbb{P}^0_k$ have degree 0.

Comment: Thank you KReiser and David for your explanation.